What is (a) Firehose (file)?
Question
What is a "Firehose file" (or its counterpart, the mere "Firehose", if that's more applicable)?
Rationale and Research
I ask because, in threads like the undermentioned:

forum.fairphone.com/t/trapped-in-fastboot-mode-with-locked-bootloader-and-corrupted-custom-rom and
xdaforums.com/t/does-twrp-function-with-non-aosp-oses.4692346

...I have been informed that it's necessary for the Emergency Download Mode (EDL) to work, which itself is necessary to recover a soft-or-hard-bricked AOSP device. However, what it actually is isn't well elaborated on.
You can see an example of this at github.com/bkerler/edl/discussions/577, where the tool is entirely about "Firehose", yet doesn't appear to explain much about how to acquire the data necessary to operate it.
Understanding this would be useful to me because I've an Amazon Fire tablet which is currently bricked, due to a failed superuser elevation after a Recovery partition wipe (in preparation for TWRP installation) leaving me with an entirely inoperable device. I don't want this to accidentally occur to a device which I care about more, without me having a way to restore it to a usable state.
(Lack of) Duplicates
Searching for "What is Firehose?" in android.stackexchange.com returns two mostly irrelevant results:

Flash avb_custom_key using EDL
Need help unbricking my Google Pixel (sailfish)


Guess you already know what it is, you're asking for qualified answer. this will help to identify your device

@alecxs, regarding "Guess you already know what it is", I have very little idea of what they are. My best estimate thus far is some kind of cryptographic signature. That post which you've linked to uses a significant amount of terminology which I'm wholly unfamilar with.

https://alephsecurity.com/2018/01/22/qualcomm-edl-1

An Firehose Programmer file (Factory Loader file) is an external bootloader. The file is provided via USB during early boot / EDL mode.
"Loaders are made by phone manufacturers from standard editions of xbl (the secondary loader) released by Qualcomm."
Source: #11
As every bootloader, the file is specific to the phone model / SoC. Manufacturers add their own security.
Firehose Programmer files aren't publicly available due its low level powers.
